# Django REST framework: Join tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to make an API view where the user inputs the name of a controller and receives the measurements it can return as a JSON.

models.py

```
class Microcontrollers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    software = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    date_installed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_battery_last_replaced = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

class MicrocontrollersMeasurements(models.Model):
    microcontroller = models.ForeignKey(Microcontrollers, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurements, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class Measurements(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    measurement = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

serializers.py

```
class SourceStationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    class Meta:
        model = Microcontrollers
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class StationMeasurementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    class Meta:
        model = MicrocontrollersMeasurements
        fields = '__all__'

class MeasurementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    station = SourceStationsSerializer()
    stationMeasurements = StationMeasurementsSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    class Meta:
        model = Measurements
        fields = '__all__'
```

The database creates IDs for each controller and measurement. My question is how can i join the 3 tables so i can find the measurements that belong to each controller.

Answer (score 0):

well you dont actually need the intermediate models in django..

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    microcontroller = models.ForeignKey(Microcontrollers,related_name="measurements",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    measurement = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

note the `related_name='measurements"`
Now Say,

```
pic = Microcontrollers.objects.get(id=1) #or any instance of MMicrocontrollers()
measurements_pic = pic.measurements.all() # will get a list of all measurements associated with pic
```

this "measurements" in `pic.measurements.all()` here is the related name. Django created the intemediate table and all that stuff.. and simplifies it.

For the output purposes

`out = MeasurementsSerializer(measurements_pic,many=True)`

will do the job.
Note: 'type' is a keyword in python